# How to make a CSR after SecKeyCreatePair make two SecKeyRef?

Tags: openssl, keychain

I use SecKeyCreatePair to create the RSA key pair. The result is two key, pubkey & privkey. Now I want to get the raw data of pubkey to make a Certificate Request. 
I can make a CSR by OpenSSL's X509_REQ* apis, but I don't known how to transform the pubkey of SecKeyRef type to raw key.
Is there anyone do this before?

Comment: Try it the other way around. Create CSR, get the certificate, then import the certificate and the private key into the keychain.

Comment: @Max, Thanks for the advice. I have hook the openssl's API and make it work fine. And I think your way can work fine too.

Comment: @tempbottle Which API did you use to convert SecKeyRef (public and private) to EVP_PKEY?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [code](ftp://ftp.samba.org/pub/unpacked/samba_3_next/source4/heimdal/lib/hx509/ks_keychain.c). The main point is that, once you have created the key pair, you have to instruct openssl to use them. To do that you need to supply the RSA key with new methods to do encryption and decryption using the keychain keys.

I've modified a bit the set_private_key function because if you want to create a CSR with openssl, you need the correct values of the public key's module and exponent.
So here it is:

```
static int set_private_key(EVP_PKEY *pkey, SecKeyRef privKey, SecKeyRef pubKey)
{
struct kc_rsa *kc = NULL;
RSA *rsa = NULL;
int ret = 0;
CFDataRef key_data = NULL;
const unsigned char * p = NULL;
OSStatus status = 0;
long len  = 0;

kc = (kc_rsa*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct kc_rsa));
if (!kc){
    GOTO_ERR("out of memory");
}
kc->item = privKey;

// we have to export the public key (CSSM does not give us a way to get 'e' and 'n')
status = SecKeychainItemExport(pubKey, kSecFormatBSAFE, 0, NULL, &key_data);
if (status){
    GOTO_ERR("SecKeychainItemExport failed");
}
p = (unsigned char *) CFDataGetBytePtr(key_data);
len =  CFDataGetLength(key_data);

d2i_PublicKey(EVP_PKEY_RSA, &pkey, &p, len);
rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
if (!rsa){
    GOTO_ERR("d2i_PublicKey fails");
}

{
    SecKeychainAttributeList *attrs = NULL;
    uint32_t size;

    if (getAttribute(privKey, kSecKeyKeySizeInBits, &attrs)){
        GOTO_ERR("getAttribute failed");
    }
    size = *(uint32_t *)attrs->attr[0].data;
    SecKeychainItemFreeAttributesAndData(attrs, NULL);

    kc->keysize = (size + 7) / 8;
}

RSA_set_method(rsa, &kc_rsa_pkcs1_method);
ret = RSA_set_app_data(rsa, kc);
if (ret != 1)
    GOTO_ERR("RSA_set_app_data");

EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey,rsa);
CFRetain(privKey);
err:
if(key_data)
    CFRelease(key_data);
return ret;
}
```